# Detect Hibernate dialect from DataSource

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jdbc, jndi

A datasource resolved this way:

```
final JndiDataSourceLookup dsLookup = new JndiDataSourceLookup();
dsLookup.setResourceRef(true);

entityManagerFactoryBean.setDataSource(dsLookup.getDataSource("jdbc/translation"));
entityManagerFactoryBean.getJpaPropertyMap().
     put(Environment.DIALECT_RESOLVERS, StandardDialectResolver.class.getCanonicalName());
```

Will give me this exception:

```
Access to DialectResolutionInfo cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set
```

Unfortunately i do not know what the concrete Database is.

How to let hibernate decide what dialect to use?

Comment: You need to set Hibernate Dialect explicitly ..... By some property of datasource.

Comment: as it looks, i am thinking this should be cause to an error.

Comment: from the error i guess it required 'dialect' property which should be set by programmer mannually. Don't you think ? Let me know if i thought wrongly then. Thanks

Comment: @Pater parden me..!! I thought you are getting issue while started to connect database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works with Hibernate 4, not sure why they droped that feature.